# How to grant write permissions to all files in eclipse work space

Tags: eclipse, permissions, file-permissions

I have an eclipse work space I was given to work on my local machine and I need write permissions on all these files. Most of them already have write permissions but about half of them prompt me that the file is read only and ask if I want to make them writable.

Is there a way to quickly grant write access to all files in an eclipse work space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Windows:

Right click on the workspace folder, select PROPERTIES >> SECURITY and give your desired user(s) full privileges on the folder. The properties will cascade down to files and folders inside the base workspace folder.